# Converting an array to digital matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

guys I need to convert this data of  the array  :X=[1  5, 2  4, 2 5] using Matlab to this matrix :

```
  [1    0   0   0   0]
  [0    1   0   0   0]
  [0    0   0   0   0]
  [0    1   0   0   0]
  [1    1   0   0   0]
```

where [1 5] are on the same column ,same for the rest [2 4,2 5].The size of the matrix [n n] is the maximum number in the array X, in which 5;

any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why entries `1,1` and `2,2` are set in the matrix?

Comment: why isn't the matrix symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `n`

```
X = [1 5; 2 4; 2 5];
n = max( X(:) );
M = zeros( n ); % n-by-n matrix
M( sub2ind( [n n], X(:,2), X(:,1) ) ) = 1

M =
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
```

---

**Edit** It is best to represent incidence / adjacency matrix of a graph using sparse matrix:

```
M = accumarray( {[X(:,2); X(:,1)], [X(:,1);X(:,1)]}, 1, [ n n], @(x) 1, 0, true )
M =
(1,1)        1
(5,1)        1
(2,2)        1
(4,2)        1
(5,2)        1
```

And

```
full(M) = 
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Hello Shai, thank you for reply , actually the array  represents graph that its nodes, connected ,i.e ,node 1 with node 5 and so on as the array shows, I want to represent this relation by using this matrix ,also , the array X ,size is (1, 3) where each pair of numbers represents and edge connected these two nodes .

Comment: @Mark You have 6 numbers in `X` - so it cannot be of size `(1,3)`.

Comment: @Mark again, why `M(1,1)` and `M(2,2)` are 1 while `M(4,4)` and `M(5,5)` are zero?

Comment: OK, just Imagine this in a grahph. node 1 connected  to node 5 , 1---->5, node 2 connected to node 4 , 2---->4 ....., this is same with incidence matrix ,but incidence matrix has only two  numbers (1) in its column ,in this matrix I want to add more (1s) in the column and sorry the size is (1,6).

Comment: Thank you very much  Shai, but sorry for this question, I'm not really good in Matlab, how can convert this to Matix?

Comment: @Mark note that the sparse `M` is also a matrix. it only **displays** as a list of indices.

Comment: Noted, and many thanks to you.

Comment: @Mark if this answer works for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the gray "V" icon beside it.